# Save outlook message as eml incomplete (body missing,attachments not opening,...)

Tags: outlook-redemption, eml

I try to save outlook mails within an SQL-BLOB-Field as eml (or raw) content.

I have a form within MS Access to get the mails from outlook code:

```
Dim objitem As Outlook.MailItem
Set objOutlook = New Outlook.Application
Set objMapiFolder = objOutlook.Session.Folders("USER").Folders("Posteingang")
Dim inboundemail As ADODB.Recordset
Set inboundemail = New ADODB.Recordset
inboundemail.Open "Inbound_EMail_Buffer", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

Set MailList = objMapiFolder.Items

Dim senderMail As String
Dim ReceiverMail As String
FillAddress
Dim SAfeMailItem
Set SAfeMailItem = CreateObject("Redemption.SafeMailItem")

For Each objitem In MailList
    If objitem.Class = olMail Then
        With objitem
            inboundemail.AddNew
            Select Case .SenderEmailType
            Case "SMTP"
                senderMail = .SenderEmailAddress
            Case "EX"
                senderMail = FindAddress(.SenderEmailAddress)
            End Select
            inboundemail!From = Left(Chr(34) & .SenderName & Chr(34) & " <" & senderMail & ">", 80)
            inboundemail!To = .To
            inboundemail!CC = .CC
            inboundemail!Subject = Left(.Subject, 80)
            inboundemail!DateReceived = .ReceivedTime
            inboundemail!uid = .EntryId
            SAfeMailItem.Item = objitem
            x = SAfeMailItem.SaveAs("c:\temp\" & .EntryId & ".eml", olRFC822)
            inboundemail!Size = .Size
            inboundemail.Update
        End With
    End If
Next objitem
Me.ctlDocuments.Requery
Set objitem = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing
```

Unfortunately the original Mail isn't saved complete
[this is the mail in outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jONBd.png)

[this is the saved .eml mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dESi5.png)

[saved eml after 5.23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Zjh4.png)

Comment: Does this happen for all emails? Or just one  particular email? What version of Redemption are you using?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, unfortunately this happens for all Mails - the version of installed Redemption is 4.8.0.1184

Comment: Have you tried the latest (5.22) version of Redemption?

Comment: I tried the latest version 5.23.0.5664 - unfortunately the same result ( see in the original post file "saved eml after 5.23"

Comment: Can you save the problematic Outlook message as an MSG file, zip it (important!) and send it to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com?

Comment: mail is on the way - is coming from blue.sky.29 (at) web (dot) de